# Open application and do a function from URL

Tags: xcode, swift

How can i open a URL link on my phone, and that url will open my application and do a function when opened?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom URL scheme for your application in the Info.plist of your project. You will have to add a parameter and select the type as URL types and within URL types , you will have to add a URL scheme and since URL scheme is an array you will have to add first element and mention the name you would want to use in your URL structure. This name is followed by (name_given_by_you):// to open the application.  as shown in the image

[image]

and to handle the call back you will have to override this method in appDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
  {

}

And to open the App using the URL you need to use the URL scheme name like SampleApp:// if you input this in the phone browser it would open up your application.

Thanks

Omkar

Comment: @IdaEmilie did you try it?